# What Formula can be used to plot a relation between stress and strain?

Tags: metallurgy, material-science

[image]

Suppose a question starts by pointing that a cylindrical sample of a certain metal (in my case it is brass alloy) was put under a load. This piece has an initial diameter and length of 1.263cm and 5cm respectively.

It then provides a table showing the **Gauge length, Stress, and Strain** of this piece with respect to the varying **Loads** it is being subjected to.

Finally, the question states that the piece has fractured and was at a Diameter of 0.935cm and gage length of 7.535cm when this happened. It then proceeds to ask to draw an **Engineering** Stress Strain curve for this sample of metal.

My question here is, what is the formula that expresses the relation between stress and strain to use for this plot, and is it the same for the plastic and elastic deformation of this sample?

Comment: Check this out: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/7354/10902

Comment: You are supposed to use the table not a formula for the relationship between stress and strain.